# create a sequence that replicates itself excluding the last element

Tags: r, vector, sequence, rep

Is there a way to create a sequence that replicates itself excluding the last element without a loop? Say we have a starting sequence `4:1` and the function `fun` that generates the rest of the sequence like:

```
> fun(4:1)
[1] 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 4 3 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sequence`.

```
5L - sequence(4:1)
# [1] 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 4 3 4
```

As function:

```
f <- \(n) (n + 1) - sequence(n:1)
f(4)
# [1] 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 4 3 4
```

Or

```
f2 <- \(seq) seq[1] + 1 - sequence(seq)
f2(4:1)
# [1] 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 4 3 4
```

For sequences not ending with 1 maybe

```
f3 <- \(s) unlist(list(s, lapply(1:diff(range(s)) - 1, \(i) s[-((length(s) - i):length(s))])))
f3(5:3)
# [1] 5 4 3 5 4 5
```

Comment: This has problems with sequences other than x:1, e.g. `f2(5:3)`

Comment: @AndreWildberg That's a point, we need different strategy for such cases, updated.

Comment: Are not `apply` functions just hidden loops?

Comment: @Deeproad Yes, just with the difference that they run in C.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `sequence` option that would work in any case:

```r
rev_seq <- function(s) sequence(rev(seq(s)), s[1], -1)
```

outputs

```r
rev_seq(5:3)
#[1] 5 4 3 5 4 5

rev_seq(4:1)
#[1] 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 4 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problem:

```
v = 4:1
unlist(lapply(4:1, rep_len, x=rev(seq_along(v)))

[1] 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 4 3 4
```

if you prefer a custom function:

```
fun = function(x) {
  nx = rev(seq_along(x))
  unlist(lapply(x, rep_len, x=nx))
}

fun(v)
[1] 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 4 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `matrix`, also works with lower bounds > 1

```
fun <- function(x){lx <- length(x); m <- matrix(x, nrow=lx, ncol=lx) 
                   m[upper.tri(m, diag=T)[, lx:1]]}

fun(4:1)
 [1] 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 4 3 4

fun(5:2)
 [1] 5 4 3 2 5 4 3 5 4 5
```

Comment: Neat +1, the loop might be hidden somewhere in the [`matrix` C codez](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/6b22b60126646714e0f25143ac679240be251dbe/src/main/array.c) though :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `head()` iteratively on the vector:

```
foo = function(x) {
  lapply(rev(seq_along(x)), head, x = x) |> unlist()
}

foo(6:2)
# [1] 6 5 4 3 2 6 5 4 3 6 5 4 6 5 6
foo(4:1)
# [1] 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 4 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the `sequence()` answer by @jay.sf - However this only works on sequences ending in 1.

```
sequence(4:1, from=4, by=-1L)
#  [1] 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 4 3 4

fx <- function(x) {
  sequence(x, from=head(x, 1), by=-1L)
}
fx(4:1)
#  [1] 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 4 3 4
fx(5:3)
#  [1] 5 4 3 2 1 5 4 3 2 5 4 3 #wrong result
```

Edit: And my approach to making a matrix and taking the "upper left triangle" is the same as @AndreWildberg .. removing:

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <- function(x) {
  x |>
  length() |>
  seq() |>
  sapply(function(y) x[1:y]) |>
  rev() |>
  purrr::simplify()
}

fun(4:1)
#> [1] 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 4 3 4
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?